# How is a csrf token obtained by the client that was never sent in any response?

Tags: http, security, curl, cookies, csrf

The csrf token on the social media platform twitter.com / x.com is stored in a header called `x-csrf-token` and in a cookie called `ct0`.

However, it seems that this token is never sent to the client on Twitter. It doesn't show up in any response body, response header (e.g. set-cookie), cookie or html-markup, and at some point it suddenly shows up in the request header of a particular request to Twitter or the Twitter API.

My question is: How can it be that the csrf token is suddenly in the request header of a request from the client to the server, without ever having been sent to the client?

Is the csrf token generated on the client side? In which request / mechanism is the csrf token passed to the client?

Comment: Why is this tagged with cURL? Is this problem even related to programming?

Comment: @NicoHaase I'm looking for the specific curl request that would have the csrf-token in the response. Why wouldn't this be related to programming? However, I could already solve it myself. To get a user specific csrf-token you have to log in first. That way it is not session bound.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by  editing it. Also, please add the code you are currently using